# c++ Nested struct map can't find member

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to make a card game and have decided to store the data of individual card types as struct inside a main struct. Which seems to work fine. However when trying to map the struct the compilers doesn't see the members.**"Art is not a member of Cards"** I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem anywhere. Help would be appreciated

```
struct Card001 {
    sf::Texture Art;

    void loadArt() {
        if (!Art.loadFromFile("Sprites/BasicCard.png")) {
            // error...
        }
    }
};

struct Cards {
    struct Card001 card0011, card0012, card0013;
};

int function_cardTexture(int card) {
    //removes the last 1
    card = card - 10000;

    std::map < std::string, Cards > Vars;

    //turn int card into a string
    std::string a = static_cast < std::ostringstream * > ( & (std::ostringstream() << card)) - > str();

    //combines card and string a into one string
    std::string nametext = "Library.card" + a;

    sf::Texture text = Vars[nametext].Art;

    return (1);
}
```

Comment: well, it isn’t, it’s part of `Card001`, i.e. `Vars[nametext].card0011.Art` works

Comment: Your right my brain was being dumb trying to kill to birds with one stone so to speak. But this still leads me into a similar problem where                                                      
`sf::Texture text = Library.Vars[nametext].Art;  `      Comes up with an identical error. I see why however i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Or more accurately how to get around it.

Comment: There is not variable named `Library`. You also seem to have a misconception that you can construct variable names via strings, you can’t. Using strings as map keys is fine though. Just remove your `Cards` class, and rename the `Card001` class to `Cards`.

Answer (score 0):

Code Vars[nametext] got an instance of Cards, and Cards indeed don't have member Art, instead it have member card0011 etc.

Which have member Art is struct Card001.

```
Cards &cards = Vars[nametext];
Card001 &card0011 = cards.card0011;
sf::Texture &art = card0011.Art;
```

Sense the hierarchy of structs that you defined.